# Simplest way to get Dead Reckoning into my game?

Tags: networking, udp, winsock, dead-reckoning

I have a game where there are many sprites flying around the screen, with the user controlling one of them with the arrow keys/WASD.

I have it set up over a network so that the host game is the one the user controls and the client game has no user input, it simply mimics everything that his happening in the host game.

All I need to do is to implement Dead Reckoning for the user controlled sprite in the client game. It moves in 4 directions, up, down, left and right.

What is the easiest way to do this/how do I go about doing this?

p.s. my host game sends the data to the client via a UDP socket using WinSock.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, sorry man. I have never used Dead Reckoning before

Comment: Well, start here: *What* does "Dead Reckoning" mean to you (or the person assigning this task)?

Comment: my game has to be prepared to handle a bit of latency so it says I have to include an appropriate Dead Reckoning algorithm. I haven't a clue where to start.

Comment: Start by researching what "dead reckoning" means. Also search for "movement prediction". (My first comment was misleading and has since been removed.)

Comment: I know that it is where you predict where the next position will be based on previous position, speed and direction but I don't really know where to start in terms of implementing an algorithm into C++

Answer (score 1):

Search EPIC Entity Position Interpolation Code. It provides a good solution to Position DR.

For the Orientation DR, I am looking for solutions...